# How to use select when network socket is always ready to read?

Tags: python, sockets, select

I use `select` like this:

```
while True:
    readReady, _, _ = select.select([src, dst], [], [])
    for ready in readReady:
        if ready == dst:
            toRead = dst
            toWrite = src
        else:
            toRead = src
            toWrite = dst

        toWrite.sendall(toRead.recv(10))
```

And it doesn't matter if `toWrite` blocks till all data is sent.  But the problem is `select` immediately returns because the socket is ready to be read while it has no data. How do I wait till there is actually some data?

Also, `print(toRead.recv(10))` prints `b''` which is empty (while I expected `select` to block).  Sockets are in blocking mode.

Comment: When `recv` returns `b''`, the socket is "at EOF": reads will never block and always return nothing.  Thus `select` says that reads will not block (they won't), and you should read and note the end-of-input condition and do something appropriate (perhaps close the socket, if it's only for reading; perhaps just stop selecting for read).

Comment: @torek You were right, You should have posted it as the answer :) thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a part of the `select` API: If `select` call returns a readable socket, you must call `recv()` on it, otherwise every subsequent invocation of select will return this socket as still readable.

If you `recv()` and get no data, then this is an indication of a closed socket.